# What is this green thing in the sea?

Tags: sea

Wondering if someone knows what is this green thing in the sea?
Bulgaria Sozopol, I took the photos myself while in a restaurant in front of the sea. I do not know what are they I asked an acquaintance and they suggested that could be something that directs the ships , but asking here to verify if it is true

[image]

[image]

Comment: Being pedantic, are you sure it's Sozopol?  In looking at the image and google, the only place that seems to have a sea wall to right and and an outcrop to the left is the beach at Chernomorets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is, as far as I can see it in the picture, indeed something to help shipping traffic. A buoy.

It looks pretty much like one in this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoy).

There are many variations, most in red and green but other colours are used at times.

Comment: It looks wrong though. A green buoy, which denotes the starboard side of a channel, ought to be pointy, not cylindrical.

Comment: @KristvanBesien there are some wires formed into a point.  Perhaps it was taken from somewhere in Region B and modified superficially.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [lateral buoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_mark) delimiting a channel for navigation.